# How to sort list with compareTo method of specific order of colors in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to make a `compareTo` method that I use to sort a list in the order of the following colors: white, yellow, orange, red, blue, purple, black. Where white is the first color.

I have an object Fruit which contains different types of fruit, these fruits are specified in extended classes. All fruits have a color (which also is in the list of colors).

I was trying to write an if-else statement so that if the color of the fruit is yellow return 1 etc. and that for all colors. But that didn't seem to work.

Can anybody help me to write the compareTo method?

Thanks in advance!

My abstract Fruit class where I implement the compareTo method:

```
public abstract class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>, Edible {

    String name;
    Color color;
    boolean fluid;


    public Fruit(String name, Color color, boolean fluid) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.fluid = fluid;
    }

    public abstract boolean isRotten();



    @Override // I don't know how to create this one correctly
    public int compareTo(Fruit fruit) {
        if (this.getColor().getName().equals("white")){
        return 0;
    }
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("yellow")){
        return 1;
    }
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("orange")){
        return 2;
    }
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("red")){
        return 3;
    }
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("blue")){
        return 4;
    }
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("purple")){
        return 5;
    }
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("black")){
        return 6;
    }
    else return -1;

}

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEdible() {
        return !isRotten();
    }
}
```

The class for Color:

```
public class Color {


    private String name;

    public static final String WHITE = "white";
    public static final String YELLOW = "yellow";
    public static final String ORANGE = "orange";
    public static final String RED = "red";
    public static final String BLUE = "blue";
    public static final String PURPLE = "purple";
    public static final String BLACK = "black";


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }




}
```

The class where I add the different fruits to a list and sort the list:

```
public class FruitSortingMachine {

    private List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Fruit sorting machine.
     */
    public FruitSortingMachine(){}

    /**
     * Sort.
     */
    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(fruits);
    }

    /**
     * Gets fruits.
     *
     * @return the fruits
     */
    public List<Fruit> getFruits() {

        return this.fruits;
    }

    /**
     * Add fruit boolean.
     *
     * @param fruit the fruit
     * @return the boolean
     */
    public boolean addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        if (!fruit.isEdible()){
            return false;
        }
        else this.fruits.add(fruit);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable approach - "I was trying to write an if else statement so that if the color of the fruit is yellow return 1 etc. and that for all colors. But that didn't seem to work" -  Why did it not work?

Comment: @Joni I tried to compare this.color to for example white and then return 0 because that's the first for the sort but got stuck in how to do it for the other colors...

Comment: If the color is "yellow" then return 1, if the color is "orange" then return 2, and so on. The exact numbers don't matter, the only thing that matters is that the numbers are in the same order as your colors

Comment: @Joni I got it like this, but it still puts Black before Red in the list...
public int compareTo(Fruit fruit) {
        if (this.getColor().getName().equals("white")){
            return 0;
        }
        if (this.getColor().getName().equals("yellow")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.getColor().getName().equals("orange")){
            return 2;
        }
      etc.

Comment: can you update the code in the question?

Comment: @Joni I've just updated the code in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd turn `Color` into enum:

```
public enum Color {

    WHITE("white", 0),
    YELLOW("yellow", 1),
    ORANGE = "orange", 2),
    RED("red", 3),
    BLUE("blue", 4),
    PURPLE("purple", 5),
    BLACK("black", 6);

    private String name;
    private int order;

    // getters, setters etc.

}
```

Then you can compare the `Color`s by the `order` field:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit fruit) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getColor().getOrder(), fruit.getColor().getOrder());
}
```

Comment: Would it make sense to take advantage of the enum value's `ordinal()` value instead of adding an explicit `order` field?

Comment: @dnault you're right, it can also be used, I thought about it, but I think although this is a bit more verbose, it's also more explicit - shows the purpose. I don't like to have logic depending on the ordering of lines in my source code. If anyone now adds a new `Color`, it can mess up the ordering. Nevertheless both approaches are fine

Comment: @dnault no, don't use `ordinal`. The Javadoc of the method makes it clear what it should be used for, and this is not it. There is an item in Effective Java specifically about not abusing ordinal, I forget which it is.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, I had no idea Joshua Bloch does not approve of using `ordinal()` like this. Item 31, for the record.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but is there also a possibility to do this without making Color a enum?

Comment: @RonnyGiezen yes, but why? This way is clean and code is concise

Comment: @Andronicus Because it is a school assignment, and in the startproject we got Color was already a class and not a Enum. I agree with you tho that an Enum much cleaner is.

Comment: @Andronicus I made the color class an Enum, I think my teacher will think its fine. It's much cleaner code like you said. Thanks!

Comment: @RonnyGiezen no problem, if there really was no other way, you would have to do the other way around, for example create a `Map` with `Color` as key and `int` (order) as value, just like in the enum and use it in the comparator

Answer (score 0):

First rename your `Fruit.compareTo` method to something else, because it's not a compareTo method. It returns a "sort key" - something that's used for sorting - so let's call it `getSortKey` for now:

```
// @Override REMOVE THIS
public int getSortKey(/* Fruit fruit REMOVE THIS */) {
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("white")){
        return 0;
    }
    if (this.getColor().getName().equals("yellow")){
        return 1;
    }
    ...
```

Now, FruitSortingMachine can sort your Fruits by comparing the sort keys:

```
fruits.sort(Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getSortKey));
```

---

Another (somewhat older) way of doing this is implementing `Fruit.compareTo`, which is easy now that you have the getSortKey method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit that) {
     return Integer.compare(this.getSortKey(), that.getSortKey());
}
```

If you do that, you can sort using `Collections.sort`

```
Collections.sort(fruits)
```